# aggregating columns in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with the covid19 datasets for Germany. Aggregating the number of `cases`, `deaths` and `recovery` by month for Germany gives me the same value. What could be wrong? Inspecting the `dataframe` shows me that they are not same.

```
covid19_data.set_index("date").resample("M").agg({"deaths": "count", 
                                                  "cases": "count", 
                                                  "recovered": "count"})


               deaths   cases   recovered
date            
2020-01-31        7       7        7
2020-02-29        76      76       76
2020-03-31      28489   28489    28489
2020-04-30      38567   38567    38567
2020-05-31      13116   13116    13116
2020-06-30      7740    7740     7740
2020-07-31        810    810      810
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Did you try `.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))` instead of `resample`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aggregating, you should be summing the values right?

```
covid19_data.set_index("Date").resample("M").agg({"deaths": "sum", 
                                                  "cases": "sum", 
                                                  "recovered": "sum"})
```

or

```
df = df.groupby(by=pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')).sum()

            deaths  cases  recovered
Date
2020-01-31      67    744         15
2020-02-29      68    777         17
```